# php mysql content load like facebook

Tags: php, mysql, lazy-loading

I wan to load data from mysql with PHP like Facebook (load data by scrolling down). I checked in many tutorial where everyone is doing by `order by ID` but I can't do so while my fetching query is like follows.

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM conferencecreate WHERE ccFlag = 1 AND ccStartingDate >= '$nowTime' GROUP BY ccTitle");
```

If I want to implement `ORDER BY ccId DESC` then its not working. Any Idea how to solve this issue?

I tried this :-

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM conferencecreate 
             WHERE ccFlag = 1 
               AND ccStartingDate >= '$nowTime' 
             GROUP BY ccTitle 
             ORDER BY ccId DESC");
```

But this produced the error

> Warning: mysql_fetch_object(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource

Comment: So add your `ORDER BY` to the query and show us how you do that. Then we can put you straight

Comment: I check with following query but not working.. 
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM conferencecreate WHERE ccFlag = 1 AND ccStartingDate >= '$nowTime' GROUP BY ccTitle ORDER BY ccId DESC");

That's my question.

Comment: In future edit your question with extra code details, comment code is almost impossible to read

Comment: So what error did that code generate

Comment: Warning: mysql_fetch_object(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource

Comment: Again, edit your question please. I have done it for you again

Comment: Why on earth do you use mysql_ functions? They are all deprecated.

Comment: What else you suggest rather than mysql_functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really should not be using the `mysql_` database extension any more but that said you need to learn how to process errors generated by any of the the mysql extensions

So try this

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM conferencecreate 
                   WHERE ccFlag = 1 
                     AND ccStartingDate >= '$nowTime' 
                   GROUP BY ccTitle 
                   ORDER BY ccId DESC"); 

if ( ! $res ) {
    echo mysql_error();
    exit;
}
```

Now you should see an error message describing what is wrong with the query you have coded.

> Please dont use the `mysql_` database extensions, it is deprecated (gone for ever in PHP7)
>   Especially if you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` or `mysqli_` database extensions,
>   [and here is some help to decide which to use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Comment: Well... its working now. Thank you..